# Counting elements in an array greater than a value and after the value

Tags: time-complexity, arrays

I have an array composed of integers from 1 through n. For each integer, I want to count the integers which are greater than that integer and occur after the integer's placement in the array in O(n*log(n)) time complexity

Ex:
array : {2, 1, 4, 3}

For 1,  4 and 3 are after 1 and greater than 1 so 3 and 4 are chosen

For 2, (1,4,3) are after 2, but only 4 and 3 are greater than 2, so only 4 and 3 are chosen

For 3, There are no elements after 3

For 4, There are no elements greater than 4

So I get something, maybe a map, that looks like: (I don't care about order)

1 - 3,4

2 - 4,3

3 -

4 -

I tried using the index placements of each integer, but the only thing I got was the number of occurrences. What I got:

1 - 2

2 - 2

3 - 0

4 - 0

Comment: Ok I suppose you know about [fenwick trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenwick_tree) or [segment trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree). You need to construct one of those over an array of size $n$ filled with zeros. The tree should supports the operations $add(i,x)$ and $sum(i,j)$ in $O(log(n))$. Now you pass trough your array right to left. Execute $add(p-1,1)$ where $p$ is the value in your array. $sum(p+1,n)$ will be the desired sum for the element $p$. For each element you make two queries thus the runtime will be $O(n\log(n))$

Comment: `…I want to count the integers…` fine. I think SE questions work better when there is an explicit question. See [How do I ask a Good Question?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @plshelp thanks for the response. I don't know about Fenwick trees or segment trees but I will check it out and try to implement your response

Comment: @greybeard thanks for the feedback. I'll look at the link

Comment: Have you been introduced to [binary search trees](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree), to [rank trees](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree)?

Comment: @graybeard No, I haven't. Do you think they would be useful for this problem?

Comment: I think a rank tree would do. Most likely, one useful answer is possible using some concept/data structure presented recently.

Comment: @graybeard aha! i looked at a rank tree and I think I figured out how to solve it. Thanks!